# Why I'm getting different result from tutorial

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86

I study on a tutorial and there is a c code like that

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
   function(1,2,3);
}
```

He says after compile this code using gcc with -S switch we will get an assembly result like that

```
pushl $3
pushl $2
pushl $1
call function
```

However when I compile it my main part looks like

```
main:
.LFB1:
.cfi_startproc
endbr64
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movl    $3, %edx
movl    $2, %esi
movl    $1, %edi
call    function
nop
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

Are both meaning the same or am I doing wrong with somewhere?

Comment: You compiled for 64 bit, while the tutorial is for 32. Use `gcc -m32`. Even then there is no guarantee you will get the same output.

Comment: there is no reason to expect any two compilers, any version of the same compiler, all the different command line options of a compiler, to produce the same output as any other combination.

Comment: the only expectation is that the output is a functional equivalent of the high level language.

Comment: Related: [Compiling C to 32-bit assembly with GCC doesn't match a book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64109864) re: getting GCC to simplify its asm output to match old tutorials (from before `-fpie` was the default, and before 16-byte stack alignment, etc.)